# Is there any method to read any file format using spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm very new to spark.

I know I can read a csv file using below method.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()

val df = spark
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .csv("/path to csv file")
```

I want to know about is there any method to read any file without considering its format using spark and Scala.

Comment: What is the point to the question? As the answer indicates the API defines what needs to be done. Do you mean an automatic detecting or just want to read it as a String?

Answer (score 1):

if you refer the spark API documentation, it has a standard set of file types which can be given as an option.

[DataReader API Doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader)

Comment: IMHO, the [DataSources documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources.html) would be a better starting point and then refer to the **API Doc**.